# How can I return different data from the same link (with image extension)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, image

The main idea is this:

I'll store some images on the server and have a list of them. Then when an user requests a particular image, let's say "lakes.png", I want to be able to return a random image from the lakes list/array, but I'm totally clueless about how to detect a request to that particular file and call the function that selects a random file before displaying it to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rewrite the request using .htaccess, e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.png$ image.php?name=$1 [L]
```

So requesting lakes.png would be redirected to image.php?name=lakes

Comment: p.s. if you then simply want to print the image back e.g. `echo file_get_contents( $image_path );`, make sure you set the correct headers, e.g. `header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );`

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try later today. (: